# Add entry to textview

Tags: android, addition, element, custom-adapter

I think the question is simple. But as a beginner I don't understand what to do.
I have read this tutorial [How to make list view with multiple textviews](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

My question is: How can I dynamically add an entry. 
Adapter.add fails. 
And I can't google because weather_data is of type weather and this is unknown. 
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: post your code n error logcat

Comment: Don't manipulate model objects directly in the adapter, modify your collection of data in your activity/fragment and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial uses a java array which is difficult to add to after it has been created:

```
Weather weather_data[]
```

The custom adapter used doesn't override the Add method either which is why it doesn't work correctly. I suggest using an ArrayList instead that holds objects of type Weather. In MainActivity:

```
ArrayList<Weather> weather_data = new ArrayList<Weather>();

weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy"));
weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.weather_showers, "Showers"));
weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.weather_snow, "Snow"));
weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.weather_storm, "Storm"));
weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.weather_sunny, "Sunny"));
```

In WeatherAdapter:

Change the type of the class variable 'data' from an array to an ArrayList:

```
Weather data[] = null;
```

to become:

```
ArrayList<Weather> data = null;
```

Change the constructor to accept an ArrayList instead of an array:

```
public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Weather> data)
```

In the getView method, you'll need to change the syntax for getting the correct array element (use the ArrayList get method):

```
Weather weather = data.get(position);
```

Then you can add items dynamically from your MainActivity. For example:

```
weather_data.add(new Weather(R.drawable.weather_stormy, "Stormy"));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. That works well. I will put a link in the comment section of the tutorial.

Answer (score -2):

Add new data into your ArrayList and call the function `adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();`
this will refresh your listview. And the new data will be added.